# how to pass this element to javascript onclick function and add a class to that clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I had an html navigation code as below

```js
function Data(string) {
  //1. get some data from server according to month year etc.,
  //2. unactive all the remaining li's and make the current clicked element active by adding "active" class to the element
  $('.filter').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="padding-left:21px;">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-left:40px;">
    <li class="active filter"><a href="#month" onclick="Data('month')">This Month</a></li>
    <li class="filter"><a href="#year" onclick="Data('year')">Year</a></li>
    <li class="filter"><a href="#last60" onclick="Data('last60')">60 Days</a></li>
    <li class="filter"><a href="#last90" onclick="Data('last90')">90 Days</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on any of the tabs

- all the remaining tabs should be unactive,
- and the current element/tab should be active,

My code above is not working.

1. How to make the above code work?
2. I only want to use javascript onclick for this. Is there any way that the `this`(current) object is send when the user clicks on the tab?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use this html to get the clicked element:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left:21px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-left:40px;">
        <li class="active filter"><a href="#month" onclick="Data('month', this)">This Month</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#year" onclick="Data('year', this)">Year</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#last60" onclick="Data('last60', this)">60 Days</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#last90" onclick="Data('last90', this)">90 Days</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Script:

```
 function Data(string, el)
 {
     $('.filter').removeClass('active');
     $(el).parent().addClass('active');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
<script>
function Data(string)
{      
  $('.filter').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('.filter').addClass('active') ;
} 
</script>
```

For the class selector you need to use `.` before the **classname**.And you need to add the class for the **parent**.    Bec you are clicking on anchor tag not the `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left:21px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-left:40px;">
        <li class="active filter"><a href="#month" onclick="Data(this)">This Month</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#year" onclick="Data(this)">Year</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#last60" onclick="Data(this)">60 Days</a></li>
        <li class="filter"><a href="#last90" onclick="Data(this)">90 Days</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    function Data(element)
    {     
       element.removeClass('active');
       element.addClass('active') ;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your code.. First you need reference to capture the element on click. Try adding another parameter to your function to reference this. Also active class is for li element initially while you are tryin to add it to "a" element in the function.
try this..

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left:21px;">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-left:40px;">
      <li class="active filter"><a href="#month" onclick="Data('month',this)">This Month</a></li>
      <li class="filter"><a href="#year" onclick="Data('year',this)">Year</a></li>
      <li class="filter"><a href="#last60"  onclick="Data('last60',this)">60 Days</a></li>
      <li class="filter"><a href="#last90"  onclick="Data('last90',this)">90 Days</a></li>
    </ul> 

</div>

<script>
  function Data(string,element)
    { 
      //1. get some data from server according to month year etc.,
      //2. unactive all the remaining li's and make the current clicked element active by adding "active" class to the element
      $('.filter').removeClass('active');

      $(element).parent().addClass('active') ;

    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" >
function openOnImageClick(event)
{
//alert("Jai Sh Raam");
// document.getElementById("images").src = "fruits.jpg";
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE

console.log(target);
console.log(target.src);
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.setAttribute('src', target.src);
  img.setAttribute('width', '200');
   img.setAttribute('height', '150');
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img);


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Screen Shot View</h1>
<p>Click the Tiger to display the Image</p>

<div id="images" >
</div>

<img src="tiger.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick(event)" />
<img src="sabaLogo1.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick(event)" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener` to pass `this` to a JavaScript function.

**HTML**

```
<button id="button">Year</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        Date('#year');
    }, false);
})();

 function Data(string)
          {
                $('.filter').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active') ;
          }
```