# Call next td using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I having table trying to get the next column value using jQuery but it's always showing blank. Here is my code

```
<table>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel('BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
<script>
function download_excel(a,b,c){
 text =  $(this).parent().next('td').text();
  alert(text);
}
</script>
```

```js
function download_excel(a,b,c){
  text =  $(this).parent().next('td').text();
  alert(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel('BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass this element to javascript onclick function and add a class to that clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998711/how-to-pass-this-element-to-javascript-onclick-function-and-add-a-class-to-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `$(this)`  .. `$(this)` in your function not refer to the element you want so you can add el `download_excel(el , a,b,c)` and change `$(this)` to `$(el)` then use `onclick="download_excel(this , 'BL8','ATR','AWFR')"`

```js
function download_excel(el,a,b,c){
     text =  $(el).parent().next('td').text();
      alert(text);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;">
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this , 'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a>
        </td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>56</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to handle inside the function without changing the html code ?

Comment: @RamanSingh what I know it's not possible .. maybe someone have another idea

Answer (score 1):

Currently [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is referring to the `window` object.

You have to pass [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function so that you can refer that as the currently clicked element inside the function:

```js
function download_excel(el, a,b,c){
 text =  $(el).parent().next('td').text();
  console.log(text);
  console.log(this.constructor.name); // window
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this, 'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thnx :) same question : Is it not possible to handle inside the function without changing the html code ?

Comment: @RamanSingh, you can target `a` but if there is multiple `a` element, the solution will not work....say, you have another identical `tr` element then how you determine which `td` to get......thanks.

Comment: thnx we have multiple tr with identical attribute except value.. will change the html code only :)

Comment: @RamanSingh, if the value is different then you check the value to target the element......again the best solution is to pass `this`.......thanks.

Comment: ya value will be different but it would be dynamic, we can't guess it during load, anyway thanks for help

Comment: Is possible help me this question too.. can we do like this to set color for all tr $(element).parents('table').prevAll("tr").css("background-color", "#f3f3f3") ?

Comment: @RamanSingh, it is not clear what you want from the selector......because there is nothing to select with `prevAll("tr")` on `table`... .may be you can update the question with what you want....

Comment: i want to change the color of all tr inside if we click on any td element, i used this one $(element).parents('table').children('tr').css("background-color", "#fbfbfb"); but no success :(

Comment: `all tr inside if we click on any td element`......I am not clear......`all tr inside` of what? Do you mean the parent `tr` of currently clicked element?.......Again it is better to update the question with the new updates.......thanks.

Comment: all tr inside -- Table.. but if we update the question then the below answers would n't make any sense..that's y no updating it

Comment: @RamanSingh, say, there are 100 rows in a table, why do you change all the rows background color on clicking on a single rows `td > a`? This does not make sense to me.......thanks.

Comment: Because i want to highlight the clicked one(already have code), rest i want to reset to previous background color.. that's y